# Why does the element inspector show this div as having non-zero width?

Tags: css, inline-styles

In the code part of Chrome DevTools, we can see that the `div`'s "width" attribute is set to 0px. But in the actual window, I can hover over it and it appears that the actual width is still 400 pixels.

Why?

Note that the `div` in question is `#raphContainer2` (note the 2), **not** the one highlighted in blue in the Chrome DevTools.

[image: What?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `width` isn't a valid attribute for your div, it should be embedded in `style`.

**Your code:**

```
<div id="raphContainer2" style="display" width="0px">
```

**How it should be:**

```
<div id="raphContainer2" style="display: block; width:0px">
```